# Ext.net parallel message bus

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, extjs, ext.net

i have some issues with Ext.net MessageBusListeners when invokings two of them at the same time with SignalR.

for example, if i broadcast in SignalR javascript function like below:

```
 <script>
        $(function () {
              var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
             chat.client.addNewMessageToPage = function (message) {
                console.log('publish: ' + message);
                Ext.net.Bus.publish(message, '');
            };

            // Start the connection.
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                console.log("start connection");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

and i define two messageBusListeners with two different Stores like below:

```
Store().ID("Store1").MessageBusListeners(new MessageBusListener
                     {
                              Name = "message1",
                              Fn = "myJSfunction",
                              Single = true
                     },...)

 Store().ID("Store2").MessageBusListeners( new MessageBusListener()
                     {
                             Name = "message2",
                             Handler = "Ext.Msg.notify('Notification', 'message2);"
                     })  ,...)
```

and i broadcast via SignalR two quick calls like :

```
Ext.net.Bus.publish("message1", '');
Ext.net.Bus.publish("message2", '');
```

the problem with this test is "myJSfunction" of the first MessageBusListener will be ignored and the handler of the second listeners will be executed instead.
If i change  the MessageBusListeners order like:

```
Ext.net.Bus.publish("message2", '');
Ext.net.Bus.publish("message1", '');
```

"myJSfunction" is executed and the handler of the first messageBusListener is executed too.

What is the problem with this case? Should i synchronize between many Ext.net.Bus.publish?

Comment: I have no idea. I could investigate if you provide a test case. Is the SignalR required to reproduce the issue? I think it might be reproducible without that. Please get rid of SignalR for a test case if possible.

Comment: even without signalR still get the same problem

Comment: Excellent. If you provide a standalone and runnable test case to reproduce the problem, I could investigate.

Comment: It is not SignaR problem. I am facing the same problem with messagebus, and publishes only the second call. I am trying to fing solution...

Comment: Dear @Daniil Veriga i think to reproduce the problem is very simple. Just publish to messages one by one. Thx a lot for your time.

Comment: Seems I remember such an issue that has been fixed already. Please clarify what Ext.NET version you are dealing with.

Comment: Dear @DaniilVeriga i am using 2.5.3

Comment: Okay, thanks. Could you test with 3.2.1? Just to ensure the issue is still there or not. Anyways, having an exact test case to reproduce it which we could copy, paste and run would help a lot.